# Facebook is not displaying the right image from pages when posting

Tags: facebook, image, post, share

i had created this web site www.almasryanews.com the problem is when posting a link like this one in facebook (not using the share button in the page)  http://www.almasryanews.com/news_details.php?id=217 i don't get the main image but i get some other images from the photo gallery in the sidebar and when using the sharing button in the page it displays the right image though i'm using

```
 <link rel="image_src" href="image path here"/>
```

how to fix this please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should specify it with adding this to your head tag

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://yourwebsite.com/path_to_your_image.jpeg" />
```

and replace your html tag with

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="rtl" xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">
```

I suggest you to :

- read more about the [Open Graph Protocol](http://ogp.me/).
- Use the [Facebook debugger](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) to know what Facebook actually *sees* (be aware of caching).

Comment: it's in the head already i'll try replacing the <html> and clear the cache by debugging

Comment: Are you sure it's already on the head? I saw some og propreties but I wasn't able to find ``og:image`` in the source code.

Comment: oh sorry my mistake i'll fix and reply

Comment: problem is still on you can check the source code. facebook still getting images from the sidebar gallery

Comment: It's because the value is : thumb/4801f.jpg, you should specify a valid url such as ``http://www.almasryanews.com/thumb/4801f.jpg``

Comment: i just did and debug tool is not showing errors but still the same problem. code updated check please

Comment: is it because the image is not larger than 200px in both directions ?